# Upload payload body to Spring Cloud Gateway before making proxy or downstream calls?

Tags: java, spring, netty, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

**Original question (Please view edit)**:

In `nginx`, there is module directive called `proxy_read_timeout`: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html - By default, it is `60s`, and as I understand it, this is only for calls between `nginx` and the `proxied service` like so:

Client (Uploads a big file) -> nginx Gateway -> (Waits 60 seconds) -> Downstream Service

In Spring Cloud Gateway, I'm familiar you can set this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        response-timeout: 60s
```

or per route using `metadata` like this:

```
.metadata(RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_ATTR, 60)
```

However, this seems to set the response timeout for the entire call chain, like so:

Client (Uploads a big file) -> (Waits 60 seconds) Spring Cloud Gateway -> Downstream Service

Is there a way to set a response timeout only between SCG and the proxied service but not the whole request? Or perhaps dynamically or programatically set the response timeout on between downstream calls?

I would like to limit the response time of the proxied call, but if a client is uploading a big file, it might take longer depending on their upload speed.

---

**Edit**: After some more research, `proxy_read_timeout` is behaving the same as SCG's `response-timeout` - The issue has been narrowed down to this config (we use openresty/lua-nginx-module)

```
lua_need_request_body on;
proxy_read_timeout 10s;
```

With the above, I observed a 30s transfer start, and then it reached the backend service

[image]

With this commented out:

```
# lua_need_request_body on;
proxy_read_timeout 10s;
```

I observed a `upstream timed out` in nginx, and transfer start getting cut short (file didn't finish uploading)

[image]

Their doc https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#lua_need_request_body indicates:

```
Determines whether to force the request body data to be read before running rewrite/access/content_by_lua* or not.
```

So they must be doing payload body processing before anything else takes over.

So the new question is, can Spring Cloud Gateway process uploading the file before any response-timeout settings kick in?

Comment: the metadata way is per route, there's not a simple way to to anything dynamically. You have to extend `NettyRoutingFilter` and override `getHttpClient()`

Comment: @spencergibb Thank you so much for your time. I narrowed down the settings from our nginx gateway implementation. Please see the edit for more details, but essentially we are using https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#lua_need_request_body and that will read the entire request body before any nginx timeouts begin. So am trying to see if SCG can process the payload body before any response-timeout settings kick in. Let me know if you find anything, thanks!

Comment: At this point its a different question as pointed out. Right now gateway doesn't handle file uploads and doesn't differentiate file upload requests from any other request